# Save button in WinFormApp SuperGridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

I am attempting to create a button that would save a data to database. The data will be edited or introduced new in SuperGridControl. I totally do not know how to do it. Any suggestions?

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.Data.SqlClient;

        namespace MyFirstWinForApp {
        public partial class Users : Form
        {

            public Users()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'testDataSet.GrupyUzytkownikow' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                this.grupyUzytkownikowTableAdapter.Fill(this.testDataSet.GrupyUzytkownikow);
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'testDataSet.Uzytkownicy' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                this.uzytkownicyTableAdapter.Fill(this.testDataSet.Uzytkownicy);


            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    MessageBox.Show("Dane zapisane", "Zapisano", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }

        } }
```

Answer (score 0):

On `Button_Click` event, you need to check the followings

1. Make a check to verify that the Grid is empty, bind new data with
   it.
2. If the `Grid` is not empty and having some data, you need to
   exclude duplicate data by comparing data within your
   `dataset/datatable` with the data within `Grid` and add unique data
   within the Grid.